# Drag controls on partial-screen modals on iPhone X

Tags: mobile, ios, iphone, modal-windows

With the introduction of the home indicator on the iPhone X (and Xs, Xr, Xs Max), it seems worthwhile to question the pull-down-to-close controls on partial-screen modals.

The most common pattern I've come across up to this point has been the horizontal drag bar:

[image]

But now, with the home indicator on iPhone X, you end up with two similar drag bars intended for swiping in opposite directions (though accomplishing a similar action):

[image]

Feels like this could be confusing for users.

In looking for alternatives, I came across this example from Apple's Podcasts app, where they use a down carat for the drag control:

[image]

Facebook floats the drag bar above the modal (the orange boxes just obscure the identity of the poster):

[image]

Of course, there's also the classic 'X' in the top right corner to exit the modal, but that seems outdated at this point.

Is there any kind of consensus on which of these interactions, if any, are preferable? Has anyone done any testing they'd be willing to share?